# Boot failure after CENTOS 7 update

Tags: centos, corruption

Apologies but I'm a newbie when it comes to web server management. I was in the process of updating our server's CENTOS 7 available packages through webmin when we suffered a power outage. No UPS unfortunately so total shutdown. Now I can't boot due to the following error message: "/lib64/libsystemd.so.0: file too short" Can anyone talk me through what I need to do to restore the corrupted OS please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to boot into [rescue mode](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Rescue_Mode/#sect-rescue-mode) on a CentOS install dvd, and reinstall the systemd packages inside the chroot.

You might need to look at what else is broken too. A ‘yum-complete-transaction’ might be necessary, if the system was reset during a yum update.